# How to get a square table?

Tags: r

I've got the following code to create a classification table in **R**:

```
> table(class = class1, truth = valid[,1])
     1  2   3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
1  357 73   0  0 47  0  5 32 20  0  4  7
2   25 71   0  0 23  4  1  0  2  1  8  3
3    1  2 120  1  5  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
4    0  0   0 77  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
5   15 27   0  0 67  6  7  0  4  1  5  7
6    1  2   0  0  2 44  0  0  0  7  7  0
7    1  1   0  0 10  0 66  0  1  0  1  7
9    1  0   0  0  3  0  0  2  8  0  0  2
10   1  1   0  0  1  6  0  0  0 17  0  0
11   0  7   0  0  3  1  0  0  0  4 10  2
12   0  1   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

However, I need this table to be a square (line 8 is missing in this example), i.e. the number of rows should equal the number of columns, and I need the rownames and colnames to be preserved. The missing line should be filled with zeros. Any way of doing this?

Comment: What's the output of `levels(class1)` and `levels(valid[,1])`?

Comment: `> levels(valid[,1])
[1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12"` and as it seems that `class1` is not a factor (but there is no 8 in the vector `class1`). Is that important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most probably comes from a difference in levels.

Try copying the levels from `valid` to `class1`:

```
class1 <- factor(class1, levels=levels(valid[,1])
table(class = class1, truth = valid[,1])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is almost right, but it's `factor` instead of `as.factor`.